# How to specify a different "top level" name for tar?

Tags: shell, tar

I would like to tar root (/) and let it appear as /abc in the tar archive.

Is there a tar flag for specifying a custom top-level name?

Comment: Should the targets of symlinks also be be modified? For instance, if there's a `/bin` -> `/usr/bin` symlink, should it change to a `/abc/bin` -> `/abc/usr/bin` symlink?

Answer (score 10):

The closest I can find is the `--transform` option. I don't know for sure, but I'm guessing this is a GNU only flag:

```
 --transform, --xform EXPRESSION
       use sed replace EXPRESSION to transform file names
```

Using that, you can pass a `sed` substitution command and change the `/` to `/abc`:

```
tar cf root.tgz --transform 's/^\//\/abc/' /
```

This will still print `/` paths when creating the archive but they will become `/abc` when you extract it.

---

Another approach, if your `tar` does not have the `--transform` option is to make `/abc` a symlink pointing to `/` and then tar that:

```
$ ln -s / /abc
$ tar chf root.tgz /abc
```

The `-h` is essential as that is what tells `tar` to follow links:

```
 -h, --dereference
       follow symlinks; archive and dump the files they point to
```

That will have the effect of setting `/abc` as the top level directory.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU tar, you can use that command:

```
tar --transform="s|/|/abc/|" -Pcf bar.tar /
```

Otherwise, here is a portable way to do it, i.e. one that doesn't rely on a GNU or other specific tar extension but is based on a POSIX tool that should be available on any Unix compliant machine:

```
pax -w -s '/\//\/abc\//' -f foo.tar /
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it which works for tarring from any location (not just /):

```
tar --transform 's|^|/abc/|' -zcvf /path/to/dest.tgz *
```

It simply appends a `/abc/` to the beginning of every path.

Comment: When extracting an archive created this way I get a warning `tar: Removing leading / from member names`. Using `'s|^|abc/|'` worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @terdon 's excellent answer, a more "didactic" example...

```
tar -czf "MY_NEW_FOLDER_NAME.tar.gz" --transform "s/^\.\/MY_FOLDER_NAME/MY_NEW_FOLDER_NAME/" "./MY_FOLDER_NAME"
```

**IMPORTANT:** Note that `^\.\/MY_FOLDER_NAME` must exactly reflect the path to the target directory "./MY_FOLDER_NAME".

**You can play around building your regex:** [SED compatible online escape character](https://dwaves.de/tools/escape/) and [GNU sed REPL](https://sed.js.org/).

**Thanks!** ✌️